# Как правильно загружать изображения для примеров HTML/CSS?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, ссылки, загрузка-изображения

Брал картинки для демонстации HTML/CSS со сторонних ресурсов. Столкнулся с тем, что изображения могут стать недействительными. После этого стал использовать Base64. Но проблема с тем, что он довольно громоздок. Возможно самый правильным было бы загрузить картинку на через форму загрузки и брать ссылку c `i.stack.imgur.com`. Какой способ задания картинки самый верный?

---

Также есть предложение: ограничить задание картинок одним способом во избежание того, что примеры с HTML/CSS становятся недействительными.

Answer (score 3):

- Если вам важно **содержимое** картинки, то можно вставить картинку просто в текст вопроса/ответа, потом вырезать получившуюся ссылку на imgur.com и использовать её в сниппете.
- Если вам важны **размеры картинки и её отображение** в полученной вёрстке, думаю что хорошо будет использовать  [placehold.it](http://placehold.it). Там на всех картинках сразу подписан размер, это же должно быть полезно для демонстраци вёрстки? К тому же, там серые картинки, которые отлично сжимаются и экономят трафик.
- Base64 мне не нравится сразу по нескольким причинам:

  - Сложно редактировать. В режиме сниппета вообще один текст накладывается на другой.
  - Читатель вынужден загружать эти лишние килобайты, даже если он не будет запускать сниппет.

Comment: А что вы думаете насчёт запрета картинки со сторонних ресурсов? В том числе и `placehold.it`? Размеры изображения можно задать и в CSS.

Comment: Также интересно ваше отношение к Base64. Вот [пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611270/220571). В ответе смотрится более-менее, но когда это редактировать — не особо…

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov посмотрел как выглядит base64. Мне кажется, это ужасно :) Редактировать крайне тяжело становится.

Comment: Хорошо, я тогда загружу на `imbur.com`. Не нравятся мне серые картинки `placehold.it`, хочется чтобы была цветная жизнерадостная картинка. И это всё равно третьесторонний сайт. А можете ответить на [первый вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4462/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-html-css/4463?noredirect=1#comment15306_4463)? Какова ваша позиция?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov смысл-то в том, чтобы картинка была доступна условно-вечно. Это условно-гарантируется при размещении её на imgur, но я думаю что placehold.it тоже достаточно надёжен. Сторонние сайты, не предназначенные для вечного хранения картинок, точно не подходят.

Comment: Отлично, поэтому вы тоже хорошо относитесь к запрету картинок не на imbur и программной реализации (исключение для вас — placehold.it)?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov да, верно. Исключение потому, что это мне кажется невероятно удобным для отладки вёрстки. Но я не занимаюсь вёрсткой, так что у профессионалов может быть другое мнение )

Answer (score 0):

Давайте запретим вставку ссылок на картинки со сторонних ресурсов. Это может сделать пример недействительным.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте запретим `src` в формате Base64. Это делает примеры очень громоздкими. Либо просто установим лимит на длину, так как бывают иногда бывают случаи, когда они нужны.